# Azure web job aborting after 1 hour automtaically

Tags: azure, web, azure-webjobs

We have a azure web job which automatically aborts after 1 hour .The app service is in premium plan

The app service Always on is set and the configurations are set the high values

SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT and WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT have been set to 172800

Also have settings.job where its configured as below

{
"timeout": "48:00:00"
}

What else needs to be done to ensure the web jobs does not gets auto aborted?

Comment: Can you share more details with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a sample code to run WebJobs continuously in web app.

**Code :**

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WebJob started at: " + DateTime.Now);
        for (int s = 0; s < 10; s++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working... " + s);
            Thread.Sleep(60000); 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("WebJob completed at: " + DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

**Settings.job :**

```json
{
    "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *", 
    "runMode": "Continuous", 
    "timeout": "48:00:00" 
}
```

I enable **Always on** is to **on** in Configuration as below:

[image]

I have added the **SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT** and **WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT** to **172800** in App Settings below:

[image]

**Output :**

It runs successfully as below:

[image]

Then, I published my code to the Azure web app services as below:

[image]

The WebJobs is running in the Azure web app service as below:

[image]

I started this WebJobs 12 hours ago, and it is still running as below.

[image]
[image]